# Why I can't use sass in a react project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, sass

So I installed `sass` with `npm i sass`, and renamed my `App.css` to `App.scss`, but I have some errors:

[image]

It says that I don't have sass, even though I installed it. I even did `npm uninstall -g sass` and installed it again.

Comment: Did you recompile the project after installing sass?

Comment: i reopened the project today and it worked, thanks!